# Computed property name is not assignable to Record type

Tags: typescript

When I try to assign a value to a `Record` using a computed property name, I get a type error:

```
function Test<N extends string, M extends {}>(name: N, model: M) {
  const record: Record<N, M> = { [name]: model };
}
```

```
Type '{ [x: string]: M; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<N, M>'.ts(2322)
```

Why does the rvalue have the type `{ [x: string]: M; }` and not `{ [x: N]: M }`?

Comment: Can you attach your Record interface?

Comment: Looks like a [longstanding known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).

Comment: @Yeheshuah it is the built in Typescript Record type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a longstanding known bug, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), where the computed property key type is widened to `string` erroneously.  Not sure if this will be fixed soon, or ever.  For now, I'd say that you should use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing:

```
function Test<N extends string, M extends {}>(name: N, model: M) {
    const record = { [name]: model } as Record<N, M>;
    return record; // to show something soon
}
const works = Test("okay", "hmm");
// const works: {okay: string}
```

---

Note that it's technically not safe to do this, in the case where `name` is not of a  single [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type.  For example, if it's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string literals, you get something claiming to have more keys than it has at runtime:

```
const coin = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "heads" : "tails";
const oops = Test(coin, "hmm");
console.log(oops.heads.toUpperCase() + oops.tails.toUpperCase()); // no compile error
// TypeError at runtime!
```

If you're not planning to pass in weird things for `name` that's fine.  Otherwise you could start going crazy to make the type of `record` as true as possible:

```
function TestSafer<N extends string, M extends {}>(name: N, model: M) {
    const record = { [name]: model } as
        string extends N ? { [k: string]: M | undefined } :
        N extends any ? { [K in N]: M } : never;
    return record;
}
```

which has the following behavior

```
const fine = TestSafer("okay", "hmm");
// const fine: {okay: string}
const better = TestSafer(coin, "hmm");
// const better: {heads: string} | {tails: string}
const alsoBetter = TestSafer(coin + "!!", "hmm")
// const alsoBetter: { [k: string]: string | undefined; }
```

That's about the safest I can imagine making things for users of `Test`, while the implementation is a big mess of assertions and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types).

---

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAFQKYGcoB4ByjUAeUqYAJuopgE4xgDmANIgLL5EnmIDeAvgHwAKMAEMAtqgBciHE1FxSqADZTmASm4AoRNsQQEmRFVR6qpRAF5uiANojxAXSlyFixD0TCKAJWNxTuJmY+AG4tHSMoECokIxNSYMQAekTEKDhKAAs4AHdKOHEoDNo6PIQNHg09MANsvwBrCks0TAEAIjg64QBPVqZWjNFRVtVQ5N19KERaqgapLg7uqWpiisqJ8doLFmFCgDoqYTJ8gXUsRAAGXYBWRAB+RH7UYXJWxClWqGEYRXRW0KqDHA4AAHRooDBQAR6Wh9AZDEZrapwRSoXaKOB0ARA0G7DJPci7NIAVWBwNQVAAwp5UCdEABqRDY9CEr4-QlwElkynUk4jJIpMDpPSiYHfVD4KhUPwaMbILpkgCikr8HkmVHAsHEAEINBpQJBYAhwZgAMrCYDk3BsYhkCjLeiBa0cCi8QR2STSWTyJQqdRcMLaAFq3ymLZcGzuxyIZxKNwedABnTae0lQg2zh4e7h6x1JZQGj0KOsAA+iHACmAtFQZncEkTSbwaedHjAXTuVmsAGlEJscEW41IwKgAG7k0JJiJRGIh+LlXVBxCVodbZpQM0WqhtBY9WGDYajFILpce+adLp5gt0CoLgBGqCgxCoK4h6-JULgMIecP3MsP6zvD7knMeLPOgF4rIgpZcJ83xgZQ+YrIiBjCD8cAAEL3o+z6muab7QkgDKtFqWq9F+e6qL+4zVJMKHoOhmFAR2ubwZeUYppBZZkKgx7xG4QA)

Comment: I couldn't find a big report on this so thanks for clearing that up! My initial solution was also to use a type assertion since my use case would only ever receive a string literal.