# Typescript function that returns a dict with keys based on function input

Tags: typescript, dictionary, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that takes as input a string, and returns a dictionary with that input string as the only allowed key. Here's what I have so far.

I have a `Dict` type, which takes a type extending string and only allows members of that type to be members:

```
type Dict<TIdentity extends string> = {
   [TAddress in TIdentity]?: number
};
```

This works correctly, for example here:

```
type typ = 'abc';
const x: Dict<typ> = {
    'abc': 1, 
    'def': 2 // type error
}
```

The type error is:

```
Type '{ abc: number; def: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Dict<"abc">'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''def'' does not exist in type 'Dict<"abc">'.
```

Now I've written this function to take a string and return a `Dict` with it as the key:

```
function get<TIdentity extends string>(
    identity: TIdentity
): Dict<TIdentity> {
    return {
       [identity]: 3
    }
}
```

The idea is that I can write code like this:

```
const result = get('def')

// correctly allowed
result.def;
result['def'];

// correctly disallowed
result.ghi;
result['ghi'];
```

But I'm getting a type error on the return from `get`:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Dict<TIdentity>'.
```

It seems that despite me using the same `TIdentity` type in `identity: TIdentity` and the return type `Dict<TIdentity>`, the `identity` key is getting treated as a string, instead of that `TIdentity` type. Is there any way that I can avoid this and have Typescript treat `identity` as a `TIdentity` for the purpose of type-checking that returned dict? I've also tried doing `[identity as TIdentity]: 3` and get the same error.

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2AHgCoEkAmEB2w6hQQAewumAzlBcAE5w4DmAfFALxQDeAUFHwNqoAgpky0IFKgygZseAiAC6AfgBcUHAFcAtgCMItbgF8A3N26hIUS+ygByAIa6EdqAB972AGZ2zCAPY4NFDE6vBIyJasHDx8fI7OduoAjAA0vHF23klQAEzG5l6aOEhwgVCMECiyuPiEJGQ4lNR0DCwAFBl8cHJ1IOo18qDcAJRhiNVYtQqssXHiwJq0OFxdcVD8PdOgiuoAzGtGBdwBQcBQ4hSaADbnHJXA7VkQPiPmAPTvUAG04kjXICgDmu138AHcIJhuJcbsAAHTeMww278Z4+RRmbifb7+X4Qf6AzBwCjA0EQqHI+GMAAWcCRElhqJpcDsGO4QA)

Comment: Not a best thing, but have you tried `return { [identity]: 3} as Dict<TIdentity>`?

Comment: Oops I hadn't, that seems to have worked! I'm not sure if there's something more type-level I should tweak but this seems like a good workaround at least for now! Thanks :)

Comment: This is [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948). A type assertion is a reasonable approach, although it does the wrong thing in the face of unions. See the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760022/computed-property-name-is-not-assignable-to-record-type) and its answer for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work without disabling the type checking of typescript

```
function get<TIdentity extends string>(key: TIdentity): Dict<TIdentity> {
    const result: Dict<TIdentity> = {}
    result[key] = 3
    
    return result
}
```

Here is a [typescript-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2AHgCoEkAmEB2w6hQQAewumAzlBcAE5w4DmAfFALxQDeAUFHwNoBrCCCgMoGbHgIgAugH4AXFBwBXALYAjCLW4BfANzdjoSFFPsoAcgCGmhFaMIA9jhpRiy%20EmSnWHHj4%20W3srZQBGABooXiCrbAAzMKgAJigAenTzcGgdWmddPWME1RwkOFcoRggUSVx8QhIyHEpqOgYWAAphEGU66VAASi9EWqx6mVZAoIAbGqhaCApVGeARn36GkH8uIqCFpZXgIRFZSwBmWL4rg%20BVWhwD5dX9Y24XN2Ano8tq4E6AER2BAAwbGRbPYAAOmB3AhR34QPsANk4MOqyhjAAFnA4ejjlZsXArKigA)